# mouse pointer on desktop is tailed by square shaped marks in 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04, mouse-pointer

I upgraded to 20.04 form 19.10 and on the desktop screen the pointer is tailed by
square shaped illustrations the illustrations goes after very quickly .The problem
is only encountred on the desktop screen . As soon as I to take screen short of this,
the tail dissappears.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the `Universal Access` settings panel, try turning off **Zoom** and **Locate Pointer**.

[image]

Comment: This fix worked perfectly for my exact same issue on 20.04.1.

Comment: yes that worked for me too! Thatt was so annoying so massive thanks

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to turn Zoom off.