# Cursor putting marks on Screen in ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Tags: 20.04, screen, ubuntu-gnome, cursor

I am using *Asus VivoBook 15 intel-core i5- 8th-gen*. After upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 its giving me the problem. The cursor on moving is leaving square marks behind for sometime on the screen.
I tried this in another machine also in that machine i am having *two root-user* in that machine also the problem is present.
**How to avoid this problem??**

[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZAd8.jpg) 
 [ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM4UV.jpg) 
 [ScreenShot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE95a.jpg)

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256513/mouse-pointer-on-desktop-is-tailed-by-square-shaped-marks-in-20-04-lts/1256589#1256589

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with screen zoom. Either one should disable zoom from settings or if someone wnts to zoom the screen he/she shouldnt put the zoom level ==1x. Inshort review the zoom settings.