# Ubuntu 20.04 works normal except the cursor (mouse pointer) is blinking almost all the time

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, cursor

I've just upgraded my DELL XPS 13 from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and it works fine so far. The only problem is the cursor is blinking most of the time especially when I move the cursor(mouse pointer) onto a clickable (firefox tab, a button on a webpage or an app on the sidebar).
I have never seen the cursor(mouse pointer) to disappear completely.

Comment: Hello, do you mean *the mouse pointer*?

Comment: Yes, mouse pointer. I've edited the post with that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off fraction scaling also fixed this issue for me. To get to this, go to:

Settings > Screen Display > Fractional Scaling

[image: Fractional Scaling Settings]

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without turning off fractional scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely related to [Cursor putting marks on Screen in ubuntu 20.4 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269202/cursor-putting-marks-on-screen-in-ubuntu-20-4-lts)
I'm not aware if it's being worked on, but if you turn off the zoom in your universal access settings and it disappears, you have your answer...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to fractional scaling for an external screen which consumes too much power. I disabled it and everything seems to be fine.